# sql query not in join & between ranges date

Tags: sql, left-join

I need some help with SQL Query.  I am trying to find record who is in not join course in 2019 dates,
i have 2 table

course_attendance
ID
STUDENT_ID
SCHEDULE_ID
ATTEND_DATE

student
ID
NAME

i found who is not in course at all, but i need include range dates in 2019 who is not join course also,

here is the syntax

```
SELECT A2.* FROM student A2 
              WHERE A2.ID  NOT IN 
                       (Select student.ID FROM 
                                     student 
                                     inner join 
                                     course_attendance  
                                     on student.id = course_attendance.STUDENT_ID
                                     )
```

> Result

3   Frank   M   1994-01-04

4   James   M   1996-06-23

5   Don M   1992-02-25

8   Benny   M   1992-05-29

9   Pomela  F   1993-02-09

11  Icarus  M   1994-11-10

12  Angela  F   1993-05-17

Comment: SELECT A2.* FROM student A2 
              WHERE A2.ID  NOT IN 
                       (Select student.ID FROM 
                                     student 
                                     inner join 
                                     course_attendance  
                                     on student.id = course_attendance.STUDENT_ID
                                     WHERE YEAR(ATTEND_DATE)=2019
                                     )
                         
SQL Error [1054] [42S22]: Unknown column 'ATTEND_DATE' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use match(where) in your subquery

```
WHERE ATTEND_DATE=2019
```

Comment: It's also possible that `WHERE YEAR(ATTEND_DATE)=2019` is needed instead, depending on the datatype of `ATTEND_DATE`.

Comment: but the problem ATTEND_DATE is on course_attendance table, they not showed up because i join from student table,

heres the errors:
SQL Error [1054] [42S22]: Unknown column 'ATTEND_DATE' in 'where clause'

Comment: It is not about, in join query, any column is present from joined table.
please make sure put the where clause at the end of subquery

Comment: thanks....after i put where clause at the end of sub query it works,

Comment: Yourwelcome, I should not tell but I need to, Please vote my answer if you like and and let me have a correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You can get your result by `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```sql
SELECT A2.* FROM student A2 
LEFT JOIN 
course_attendance CA on A2.Id=CA.STUDENT_ID AND DATEPART(YEAR,ATTEND_DATE)=2019
where CA.STUDENT_ID IS NULL
```